# GL552VW Ubuntu installation issue (Graphics NVDIA960M) issue

Tags: 16.04, drivers, grub2, nvidia, asus

I need to install ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on to my laptop ASUS GL552VW.
It has a graphics card of NVDIA 960M and i7 processor.

[However, during installation, it always stops at this point[purple screen]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JrUv.jpg)

Because the default graphics driver for linux is nouveau, I tried to add nouveau.modeset=0 when editing grub2. However, it still wouldn't work.

Below are photos of the steps.

At this point, I pressed E to edit grub2

Next,[I typed in nouveau.modeset=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJeNn.jpg) and rebooted with F10

However, after this step, it still shows the purple screen

Is there anything I am missing?
Thank you.